# Hyperopt: initializing the search with manually defined points

Tags: python, hyperparameter-tuning

So I am making a transition from the bayesian_optimization (bayesopt) package to hyperopt. A great feature of bayesopt is that it allows to initiate the search with [manually selected points (probing)](https://github.com/bayesian-optimization/BayesianOptimization?tab=readme-ov-file#3-guiding-the-optimization). The motivation is that I want to ensure that the search process will evaluate a machine learning algorithm on the default parameters.

Is it possible to achieve that in Hyperopt? If yes, what is a good and straightforward practice to achieve that?